# Azure Mobile Service for operations on asp.net mvc localdb database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I have created an ASP.NET MVC website and my database is in localdb. Now I want to create a windows 8.1 mobile app that connects to the same database and to do this I need Azure Mobile Service. So how should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use Web API in your Web app to create a RESTful service that you'll query with your mobile app.  No need to use Mobile Services.

Comment: I only know ASP.NET MVC

Comment: I don't know how to use Web API with my ASP.NET MVC website

Comment: If you could tell me the steps to follow then I am ready to learn and do something new

Comment: So after learning about Web API I will be able to use my mobile app to perform ops on an existing database in my ASP.NET MVC Website?

Comment: That's what the answer states

Comment: fair enough and is it the simpler than using Azure Web Services?

Comment: Is there a big learning curve for this because I need to get this done in a short time?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use azure mobile services with an existing client you might want to take a look at this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-use-existing-sql-database/#exploring-the-existing-database-model

it shows you how to create your own azure mobile service that can connect to an existing database to be consumed by the azure mobile services client. essentially you'll be making your own separate Mobile Service website that runs along side your existing MVC site that your mobile clients can consume.

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but it took me a while to find this article myself, so I hope this is helpful!

Comment: I had found this article but it will change the schema of my database and also the name of primary keys is there a better solution?

Comment: I believe azure mobile services requires you use a specific schema for your data for certain fields it needs to operate, specifically from the ITableData interface (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.mobile.service.tables.itabledata.aspx). I haven't found any documentation on deviating from this requirement while still being able to use azure mobile services, so if you can't conform to that, your only option would be to build your own API service as CSharpRocks suggested, and you wont be able to use the azure mobile client, but have to build your own as well